# C++ string input without newline in console

Tags: c++, string, newline, cin, getline

As I wrote in the title, I would like to get a string input (with simple methods) without produce a newline in the console.

I searched in the web for more than an hour and couldn't find an answer to this simple question...why?

My program will be a simple Vocabulary trainer: I would like to write a French word and its translation in German into a text file. Therefore I first want to get the French word with

```
getline(cin, word_french);
```

Then I would like to print a " - " and after that I want to get the German word.

The problem is that after writing the French word, the "enter" will produce a newline in the console. So how not to get a newline after the string input?

I would like to appear it like this in the console:

```
(inserted french word) - (inserted german word)

string word_french, word_german;
cout<<"Beginn with the french word"<<endl;

ofstream out;
out.open("test.txt", ios::app);
std::cin.sync(); //clear buffer

getline(cin,word_french); //here the enter will produce the new line...

out<<"\n" +word_french;

cout<<" - ";
getline(cin, word_german);
out<<";"+word_german;
out.close();
```

Please try to keep it simple...

Comment: you could do it on Windows using `_getch`

Comment: Try hitting `Ctrl-D` instead of 'Enter'.

Comment: Why do you use `cout << "\n" **+**word_french` instead of `cout << "\n" **<<** word_french`?

Comment: To read a single word, you could use `cin >> word_french`.

Comment: _getch? How exactly? Isn't it only for chars? hitting Ctrl-D..well a normal user always would use enter... thx thomas matthews for this suggestion, but this don't solve my problem ;) cin doesnt work because sometimes i have to insert 2 words in the string, then the cin will just get the first one!?